# Submit a smaller result to Scoreloop

Tags: java, android, scoreloop

In an Android app, I included Scoreloop for a global leaderboard. I have 3 modes. 2 of them work correct (if a higher result is reached, the score will be submitted). But the third mode should work the other way. If a result is less/smaller than the score on the servers it should be submitted. I really can't get it working ... Sadly I haven't recived an answer when I postet this question in the Scoreloop forum.

Comment: Could you post what you've tried so far, a quantitative example of what you want, and any errors you might be seeing? Those would be helpful for answering your question.

Comment: I tried to implement it with "result" and "minor result". Also I set the sorting to ascending (but I think that's just formating ...). The situation is always the same: only higher results are submitted ...

Comment: @user1556760 Did you manage to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue. I was trying to submit a lesser score to the leader board, as my player's standing on the leader board is dynamic in both directions.

But, seems like Scoreloop doesn't want to acknowledge the a lesser score than that of which is  previously submitted.

```
Example: 
    Update A : 0    Coins - Scoreloop shows  0   Coins - DESIRED
    Update B : 8000 Coins - Scoreloop shows 8000 Coins - DESIRED 
    Update C : 4500 Coins - Scoreloop shows 8000 Coins - UNDESIRED
```

I don't remember reading about such a behavior in Scoreloop documentation. Or is it mentioned somewhere, and I missed it?